# What is the block size of the iphone filesystem?

Tags: iphone

Is it worth it for me to compress a 1000 byte file to a 300 byte file? or will the filesystem space consumption be the same?

I'm looking at storing 10k less than 4k files on my iphone and I'm curious if I'll see space saving by compressing them.

Thank you,

Carl

Comment: iPhone has 8GB+ space for your files. Do you really think that those few extra KBs you will save will give you any benefit?

Comment: It's not necessarily always a space issue - some filesystems have better or worse performance depending on how the files stored get aligned with blocks and whether the filesystem performs tail packing. Especially with 10k+ files, the potential small savings per file can add up pretty quickly if the filesystem is configured correctly.

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try and share your experiences in an answer to your question?

Comment: I'm getting to a proper test. As a side note Itunes will lie about how much free space is on your iphone.  I've installed a 30MB application on an iPhone with 37MB of free space, then unpacked an 80MB database file.  (It did take awhile though.)

Comment: how about combining your large number of tiny files into a smaller number of bigger files?  then you could compress those if you wanted...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The iPhone uses an HFSX filesystem, with an 8k block size on the user partition:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct statfs *mntbufp = NULL;
  getmntinfo(&mntbufp, 0);

  unsigned i, count = 0;

  count = getmntinfo(&mntbufp, 0);
  for (i=0; i<count; i++)
  {
    char *volName = mntbufp[i].f_mntonname;
    printf("Volume %s blocksize: %lu\n", volName, mntbufp[i].f_bsize);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

returns

> ```
> Volume / blocksize: 8192
> Volume /dev blocksize: 512
> Volume /private/var blocksize: 8192
> Volume /Developer blocksize: 4096
> ```

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for, but get a compile error:

Definition of 'struct statfs' must be imported from 'Darwin.sys.mount' before it is required.

Comment: add #include <sys/mount.h>

Comment: Based on @Louis-Gerbarg answer, I wrote [simple app](https://github.com/MelnykTaras/FilesystemClusterSize) to print information about mounted volumes to console. BTW, on iPhone 5s iOS9 32Gb block size is 4 kb. I guess, it depends on storage size and file system type (HFS or APFS).