# iOS get file size on disk

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, size, disk

I'm trying to get the size on disk of a file in iOS using Objective C. As of now I've been able to get the actual size of the file and other file information using
`NSFileManager` and then getting the attributes `attributesOfItemAtPath:error` but not the size on disk. I also tried getting the file size from `struct stat` but again it doesn't give me size on disk.I tried using `NSTask` to make a call to `du -h` but iOS didn't allow me to fork other processes. Any ideas are welcome :)

I know this questions is similar to many others but the difference is that I'm trying to do this in iOS and most of the methods used in other systems don't work here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: It's worth reading Nikolai Ruhe's answer to the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28660040/97337.

See [What is the block size of the iphone filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315311/what-is-the-block-size-of-the-iphone-filesystem) for information on the iOS block size. The size of a file on disk will be it's `stat` size rounded up to the next block.

Comment: So basically I need to find the block size. I was thinking on using `st_blocks * 512` but I don't know if `st_blocks` is always the number of 512 bytes or this varies from OS to OS? Are there any methods to get the block size?

Comment: getmntinfo(). See the linked question (What is the block size of the iphone filesystem?" The answer is 8k.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Obviously, I read the link but I want to know if it's possible using `st_blocks * 512`. This depends on whether stat always reports `st_blocks` in units of 512. It seems to me that this is the case.

Comment: Sorry; I misunderstood. Yes, st_blocks is always in 512 byte units, no matter what the filesystem block size is.

Comment: A file's allocated size on the volume is even more complex to determine. There's meta data (extended attributes are extensively used on iOS and that takes up space). Also, HFS supports file system level compression that might actually reduce allocated space. Cocoa has support to get most of this information using `NSURL`'s `NSURLTotalFileAllocatedSizeKey` property. There's some more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28660040/104790).